# Is it possible to add a reference and not load the associated DLLs

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, .net-3.5

I have a Winforms application that relies on a 3rd party SDK. I've included the .NET reference in the application, but don't always need/use it. If I try and execute the program on a machine without the DLLs it will not open at all: it won't even enter `Main`.

**Is it possible have a reference but instruct it to only load the DLLs when required?**

(PDFSharp (another reference I use) appears to only load when a PdfSharp method is called, which makes me wonder if it's something I can control.)

**Edit**...I can't see any 3rd party reference in the `Program` class, but just in case here it is:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace MyProgram
{
    static class Program
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// The main entry point for the application.
        /// </summary>
        [STAThread]
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Application.EnableVisualStyles();
            Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);

            try
            {
                Application.Run(new Main(args));
            }
            catch (Exception Ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(Ex.Message, "The program has quit :(", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);

                string TracefileContents = "Please email this file to some@body.com\n\n" + "Exception:\n" + Ex.Message + "\n\nStack trace:\n" + Ex.StackTrace.ToString();

                System.IO.File.WriteAllText("Issue Report " + DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd-HH-mm-ss") + ".dat", TracefileContents);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: .NET is pretty good about stuff like this.  The DLL shouldn't be called until you actually use it (try for yourself, run the program without the DLL and see how long until it crashes).

Comment: The point is the program won't even open (enter Main) without the DLLs - i.e. before I call anything.

Comment: It should be able to get into Main, unless you're referencing something in that DLL from a static member of the same class that contains Main, or if Main actually contains references to types within that DLL.

Comment: I have a static extension class which has methods in referencing the DLL ... would that do it?

Comment: Is it windows or web app? This can make a difference

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever I've put my "main" code above. Could it be something else? I've been on a "static field hunt" but so far no luck.

Answer (score 1):

.NET does that automatically, everything is loaded on demand by default.

Answer (score 1):

Assemblies are only loaded when you start using some type from the assembly. Just having a reference to the assembly has no impact on the run-time behavior of the application

To be more accurate, CLR loads an assembly only when a it JIT-compiles a method that uses that type. This also includes using a type that derives from/implements one of the classes/interfaces of the assembly.

Even instantiating a class that have a field or property of a type from another assembly, does not enforce loading the assembly. Unless the field or property is being accessed in the class' constructor. For example when you set a field's value in its definition statment:

```
// `TypeFromAnotherAssembly` is loaded when the class is instantiated
class Test
{
    private TypeFromAnotherAssembly myField = CreateTypeFromAnotherAssembly();
}
```

compiler emits initialization code in the class' constructor. Then, according to the rule above, when the constructor is JIT-compiled (the class is instantiated for the first time), the CLR loads the assembly. This also includes setting the field's value to `null`:

```
// `TypeFromAnotherAssembly` is loaded when the class is instantiated
class Test
{
    private TypeFromAnotherAssembly myField = null;
}
```

This does not happen when you omit the initialization statement, although the result is exactly the same (the .NET runtime automatically initialized class fields to `null` or `0`):

```
// `TypeFromAnotherAssembly` is NOT loaded when the class is instantiated
class Test
{
    private TypeFromAnotherAssembly myField;
}
```

You should be careful about static fields' initialization, because accessing the class in any way causes the initialization to occur.

Comment: Using types from the reference in an extension doesn't count, right?

Comment: What do you mean of "an extension"?

Comment: I do have a static field - so that'll be it, I guess, even though it's not instantiated?

Comment: And when you say "Even having a property of one of the a type does not enforce loading the type's assembly" ... I presume if it's a static property it would be upset and continue to fail?